# What is the correlation between a Mississippi county's African-American population and percent of votes for Hillary Clinton?

Tags: united-states, voting, demographics, hillary-clinton

I was looking at Mississippi's electoral map. I noticed that the percent of African-Americans had a close roughly 1:1 correlation with the % of votes in the county cast for Hillary Clinton. The correlation exists in Alabama, but it is not as strong. What is the correlation between a MS county and the percent of votes for Hillary Clinton?

For example, the state is 40% H.Clinton and 37% African-American. The AA number is from the 2010 census.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by correlation. You can look up Clinton's vote share among white voters and black voters in Mississippi easily. What else are you asking about?

Comment: Let me explain what I mean. County level Black/African-American population percentage cross referenced with % votes for Clinton in that county.

Comment: Example at actual county level: Adams County. 56% Clinton and 54% black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The data](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/usa-2016-presidential-election-by-county/table/?disjunctive.state) is easily downloaded from opendatasoft.com. The correlation is clear as expected, something close to 1:1. Here's a quick plot. Probably the most obvious outlier is Green County, which is 26.4% African American but voted less than 18% for Hillary Clinton. <strike>It makes me wonder if there was some kind of voter suppression going on there but I have no direct evidence for that.</strike>

EDIT: JamesK has pointed out that Greene County skews heavily male. There are also several outliers in the other direction, like Lafayette County which is 24% black but voted over 40% Democrat in 2016.

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: That makes sense. I think that it might be in that county bc of there being no DMV nearby.

Comment: And as I look closer, there may be more counties skewed just as far in the other direction, e.g. Lafayette County is 24% but voted over 40% Democrat in 2016.

Comment: Hmm. That's the opposite type of outlier.

Comment: No, [an outlier is an outlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) whether it is above or below the trend, and the overall trend here looks pretty close to 1:1.

Comment: The speculation on voter suppression is out of place on an otherwise clear and factual answer. Please consider removing it.

Comment: According to wikipedia Greene county skews "male" (for every 100 adult women, there are 141 men).  And men voted disproportionatly for Trump in 2016.  I think this explains its outlier status.